# How do I remove the Seedprod lite function error message?

Tags: css, wordpress

I installed seedprod lite on Wordpress.com and am getting an error message: function (e,n,r,i){return fn(t,e,n,r,i,!0)}
function (e,n,r,i){return fn(t,e,n,r,i,!0)}

It’s showing up in places where there are spacers in the landing page builder. For example, the header and footer are 3-column but the center column has a spacer with no content.

Anyone know what it is and how to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Tried removing the spacer but messed up design. Shows up on desktop and mobile.